# Nested FOR loop for my web scraper halfway working (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested-for-loop

I am trying to write a web scraping function that does a few things:

1. Determines the number of URL's to scrape based on a list of URL's
2. Creates a separate file for each URL
3. Scrapes the TEXT from each URL
4. Inserts the result of each text-scrape into the designated file that was just created

Here is the current code:

```
#this is the array of URL's

urls = ['https://calevip.org/incentive-project/northern-california',
        'https://www.slocleanair.org/community/grants/altfuel.php',
        'https://www.mcecleanenergy.org/ev-charging/',
        'https://www.peninsulacleanenergy.com/ev-charging-incentives/',
        'https://www.irs.gov/businesses/plug-in-electric-vehicle-credit-irc-30-and-irc-30d',
        'https://afdc.energy.gov/laws/12309',
        'https://cleanvehiclerebate.org/eng/fleet',
        'https://calevip.org/incentive-project/san-joaquin-valley']

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
from websites import urls

def scrape():
    for x in range (len(urls)):
        f = open("test"+str(x)+".txt", 'w')
        for url in urls:
            page = requests.get(url)
            #this line of code creates a Beautiful Soup object that takes page.content as input
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser") 
            results = (soup.prettify().encode('cp1252', errors='ignore'))
            #we need a command that enters the results into the file we just created.
            f.write(str(results))
```

So far, I am able to get the function to perform steps 1 & 2. The problem is the text scrape from the first website are being placed into all 8 of the .text files, instead of the text scrape from the first website being placed into the first .text file, the text scrape of the second website being placed into the second file, the text scrape of the third website being placed into the third file...etc.

How do I fix this? I feel like I am close but my second FOR loop isn't written correctly.

Comment: The error is on line 19. There are only 16 lines of code shown here. Also, what do you think *soup.find()* will do?

Comment: what is the url list and what is the data you want to save from each url?

Comment: @DarkKnight got rid of it. thanks!

Comment: @balderman added this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


urls = ['https://calevip.org/incentive-project/northern-california',
        'https://www.slocleanair.org/community/grants/altfuel.php',
        'https://www.mcecleanenergy.org/ev-charging/',
        'https://www.peninsulacleanenergy.com/ev-charging-incentives/',
        'https://www.irs.gov/businesses/plug-in-electric-vehicle-credit-irc-30-and-irc-30d',
        'https://afdc.energy.gov/laws/12309',
        'https://cleanvehiclerebate.org/eng/fleet',
        'https://calevip.org/incentive-project/san-joaquin-valley']
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

def scrape():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        i = 1
        for url in urls:
            try:
                page = session.get(url, headers=headers)
                page.raise_for_status()
                with open(f'test{i}.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(BS(page.text, 'lxml').prettify())
                    i += 1
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Exception while processing {url} -> {e}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape()
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!! @DarkKnight